# Error in Notification Part

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working with the notification part of the project, in this I want the sound notification which will notify the user about the activity. The code I am working with is below:

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate {

       UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
       if (localNotif == nil)
       return;
       NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
       NSDateComponents *dateParts = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       [dateParts setHour:18];
       [dateParts setMinute:20];
       [dateParts setSecond:00];
       NSDate *sDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateParts];
       NSLog(@"date :  %@", sDate);
       localNotif.fireDate = sDate;
       localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
       localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
       localNotif.alertBody = @"Hello Testing";
       localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
       NSLog(@"notification started");
   }
```

With the help of this code I am getting the written notification on my device but I don't hear any alert sound when notification is alerted. 
Please have a look on the code and try to locate my error. Your help will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your console.

```
date :  0001-01-01 17:26:32 +0000
```

You have scheduled the notification ~2000 years in the past, because you didn't specify components for year, month and day. Setting a [fireDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate) that is in the past means the notification is delivered immediately.

If you want to schedule a notification for today at 18:30 you could do something like this:

```
// get year, month and day components from current time
NSDateComponents *dateParts = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateParts setHour:18];
[dateParts setMinute:20];
[dateParts setSecond:00];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in active state it will not give alert sound, put it in background and test it.

NOTE: make sure your system volume is on .

Comment: i am testing it in device….

Comment: is your application in background state or suspended or not running?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have notification sound for this app disabled in Settings/Notification Center?